# GPS Week Number Rollover (WNRO) and gpsd

Tags: python, gps, gpsd

I'm looking for a solution to fix 'old' gps with the week number rollover problem.

So I created a python script "[fix_gpsrollover.py](https://gist.github.com/pepitooo/2d911cf49fc88ffd3555cbe49d276bd0)" to rewrite the nmea RMC tag to fix the date.

```
    if line.startswith('$GPRMC'):
        rmc_data = line.split(separator)
        if len(rmc_data) > 10:
            date = rmc_data[9]
            corrected_date = (datetime.strptime(date, '%d%m%y') + timedelta(days=1024*7)).strftime('%d%m%y')
            rmc_data[9] = corrected_date
            rmc_line = calculate_checksum(separator.join(rmc_data))
```

So I'm able to start manually gpsd to take fixed stream.

`$ cat /dev/ttyACM3 | python fix_gpsrollover.py | gpsd -n -N /dev/stdin`

I would like to setup correctly gpsd service to take this, I would like to use standard configuration files '/etc/default/gpsd'

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to use the output of my script to be the input of gpsd.

A start a script with supervisord at boot time.

`command=bash -c "tail -f /dev/ttyACM3 | python /home/####/fix_gpsrollover.py | nc -l localhost 42991"`

and in `/etc/default/gpsd`

```
DEVICES="tcp://localhost:42991"
```

of course the port `42991` can be changed as you prefer